# faster way for Search in multiple databases

Tags: php, python, mysql, full-text-search, query-performance

I am working on big eCommerce shopping website. I have around 40 databases. i want to create search page which  show 18 result after searching by title in all databases.

```
(SELECT id_no,offers,image,title,mrp,store from db1.table1 WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$searchkey') AND title like '%$searchkey%')
 UNION ALL (SELECT id_no,offers,image,title,mrp,store from db3.table3 WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$searchkey') AND title like '%$searchkey%')
 UNION ALL (SELECT id_no,offers,image,title,mrp,store from db2.table2 WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$searchkey') AND title like '%$searchkey%') 
LIMIT 18
```

currently i am using the above query its working fine for 4 or more character keyword search like laptop nokia etc but takes 10-15 sec for processes but for query with keyword less than 3 characters it takes 30-40sec or i end up with 500 internal server error. Is there any optimized way for searching in multiple databases. **I generated two index primary and full text index with title**

> Currently my search page is in php i am ready to code in python or any
>   other language if i gets good speed

Comment: Is the issue specific to PHP or mysql? It sounds like the issue is with mysql executing too long for < 3 character searches. If that is the case the parent language won't matter.

Comment: Regardless of hardware or programming language, you will not be able to achieve high speed if you are going to search through multiple databases (especially if databases are located on separate servers). Best thing to do would be to create one single table containing a cached copy of all the different items of each store into one table. To update the cached table, you could create a PHP script to update the items and run it periodically through using CRON job (if your server supports it).

Comment: @chris85 yes this is mysql problem i think .. there is a reason why < 3 character is slow because i used full text with match against and its only  support >3 character <3 character will be used as default %like% statement. but i mentioned as parent language so that i can found any alternative like machine learning etc which help me to build fastest way for search

Comment: @KevinHR The main problem is that my hosting plan offers unlimited databases of 1gb each that's why i have to store  all products in multiple databases

Comment: It's true that FULLTEXT search does not handle words shorter than three characters.  It's also true that `LIKE '%whatever%'` is notorious for being the slowest imaginable way to search a database.

Comment: is there alternative way you know @O. Jones

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sphixmachine:http://sphinxsearch.com/. This is powerfull search for database. IMHO Sphinx this best decision
 for search in your site.

Comment: i don't want to use any tool instead i want to program it because somewhat using tools decrease web performance

Comment: @gourav bajaj it is not decrease web performance. Like programmer you must undarstand: 1)Regular query requests are unlikely to work quickly 2)If you want to write the search yourself, while fast and which would fit into the architecture of your application, then you will spend a very very long time. 3)Sphinx machine use a lot of popular sites, which indicates its effectiveness.Look at sites list and think about it again: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

FULLTEXT is not configured (by default) for searching for words less than three characters in length. You can configure that to handle shorter words by setting a `...min_token_size` parameter.  Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html  You can only do this if you control the MySQL server. It won't be possible on shared hosting. Try this.

FULLTEXT is designed to produce more false-positive matches than false-negative matches. It's generally most useful for populating dropdown picklists like the ones under the location field of a browser. That is, it requires some human interaction to choose the correct record. To expect FULLTEXT to be able to do absolutely correct searches is probably a bad idea.

You simply cannot use `AND column LIKE '%whatever%'` if you want any reasonable performance at all.  You must get rid of that.  You might be able to rewrite your python program to do something different when the search term is one or two letters, and thereby avoid many, but not all, `LIKE '%a%'` and `LIKE '%ab%'` operations. If you go this route, create ordinary indexes on your `title` columns. **Whatever you do, don't combine the FULLTEXT and LIKE searches in a single query**.

If this were my project I'd consider using a special table with columns like this to hold all the short words from the `title` column in every row of each table.

```
id_pk INT autoincrement
id_no INT
word  VARCHAR(3)
```

Then you can use a query like this to look up short words

```
  SELECT a.id_no,offers,image,title,mrp,store 
    FROM db1.table1 a
    JOIN db1.table1_shortwords s ON a.id_no = s.id_no
   WHERE s.word = '$searchkey'
```

To do this, you will have to preprocess the `title` columns of your other tables to populate the shortwords tables, and put an index on the `word` column. This will be fast, but it will require a special-purpose program to do the preprocessing.

Having to search multiple tables with your `UNION ALL` operation is a performance problem. You will be able to improve performance dramatically by redesigning your schema so you need search only one table.

Having to search databases on different server machines is a performance problem. You may be able to rig up your python program to search them in parallel: that is, to somehow use separate tasks to search each one, then aggregate the results.  Each of those separate search tasks requires its own connection to the data base, so this is not a cheap or simple solution.

If this system faces the public web, you will have to redesign it sooner or later, because it will *never* perform well enough as it is now. (Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.) Many system designers like to avoid redesigning systems after they become enormous. So, if I were you I would get the redesign done.

Comment: i am using shared hosting so can't configure. I used

 AND column LIKE '%whatever%'

 because without it result is less irreverent
. 
No i don't have value of short word i am looking for it in title like for e.g.  search car in car gear box or like hp in hp 630 laptop. mug in plastic mug glass mug etc

Comment: i think my all database is on same server.. does JOIN do better performance that UNION ALL?? 
Yes u r right i will have to redesign it later and i willing to redesign it now that's why i posted the question  

and search only in one database then join the result will help. OK,  it will somewhat get faster as i only wanted to fetch 18 products at a time but fetching next 18 will take lots of job done. I am thinking this as my last solution.

Comment: No, `JOIN` is not a substitute for `UNION ALL`.

Comment: ok i think you have a fair point Whatever you do, don't combine the FULLTEXT and LIKE searches in a single query ...is there any way i perform %like% query on the result of Full text query

Comment: Do the FULLTEXT in a subquery, and use an outer query to further filter your result set.

Comment: sounds good but what i am thinking AND is already a shorthand operator it for e.g PART 1 AND PART 2. if PART 1 is false the result will be false so PART 2 won't  execute until PART 1 is true means SQL first scan table for FULL TEXT when result ( first row) found it will check for LIKE if not then skip the LIKE and then check for next and then for next row and so on... so indirectly its first query for FULL TEXT then query for LIKE it won't change anything what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If your focus is on searching, then bend the schema to facilitate searching rather than the other way around.

- Collect all the strings to search for in a single table.  Whereas a `UNION` of 40 tables does work, it will be ~40 times as slow as having the strings collected together.
- Use `FULLTEXT` when the words are long enough, use some other technique when they are not.  (This addresses your 3-char problem; see also the Answer discussing `innodb_ft_min_token_size`.  You *are* using InnoDB, correct?)
- Use `+` and boolean mode to say that a word is mandatory:  `MATCH(col) AGAINST("+term" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
- Do not add on a `LIKE` clause unless there is a good reason.